# Replace a string only if it exists inbetween two substrings

Tags: python, regex

For my project I need to replace any character that is inside two substrings. Here's what I mean:

```
string = "This is outside of the object. %This is inside the object.% Outside again!"
```

After replacing any `" "`'s inside `%` with a `-`, this is what the string should look like:

```
This is outside of the object. %This-is-inside-the-object.% Outside again!
```

What function can I use to do this?

Comment: how it should behave for this string? `Outside %This is inside% what now?% Outside`

Comment: It should behave like how you open/close strings. Say you have a string, `This is outside, %now inside%this is now an unclosed area% This is actually outside`.
I'd prefer just ignoring when there is an unclosed area, so that the replaced the string turns into `This is outside, %now-inside%this is an unclosed area% This is actually outside`

Comment: Scratch what the above comment says. I just need it to replace if it exists inbetween two of the substrings.

Comment: @liked21 Does every opening `%` have a closing `%` or not? In other words, is the string guaranteed to _always_ have an _even_ number of `%` chars? Because if not, I don't think this would be possible using pure regex in python. I could be wrong though.

Comment: An easy non-regex solution would be to split the string on `%` and then iterate the array replacing space characters with hyphens in every _second_ element of the array _except the very last element_. Then, you can re-join the array into one string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = "This is outside of the object. %This is inside the object.% Outside again!"
import re
Variable2 = re.sub("%[^%]*%", lambda x:x.group(0).replace(' ','-'), string)
```

output

```
'This is outside of the object. %This-is-inside-the-object.% Outside again!'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of `[^]]` is. Did you intend to use `[^%]`?

Comment: Yeah you are right , i am also very new to python ...hence i didn't think it through completely ..sorry if i'm wrong.

Comment: Is there any way for this to work for seperate substrings? Like `(` and `)`.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. The regex pattern is `\([^\(\)]*\)`.